# What is the term for $F(x)/[1-F(x)]$ where $F(x)$ is CDF

Tags: random-variable

In a research project, I developed a result which consists of a condition on $F(x)/[1-F(x)]$, where $F()$ is the CDF of the random variable $X$. What is the term for $F(x)/[1-F(x)]$? Does it have any known properties?

Comment: The ratio of probability of $A$ over the probability of $\lnot A$ is the **odds**. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds

Comment: @Sycorax Thank you very much.